# When you move towards someone or something

Tags: word-usage, word-request, verbs, phrasal-verbs

**Editted:**

When someone comes up to you, they approach you while they are moving towards you. But what (phrasal) verb is used in an opposite case?

For instance, you say:

> - The small girl **came up to me** and asked for money.

But how about a case when you go towards someone else? Please have a look on the example below:

> - She was really gorgeous. After that ceremony, I was waiting for a friendly gathering to meet her for the second time. Yesterday, we had a party to which she was invited too. When everybody was dancing, I ................... to her and after greetings started talking to her and fortunately we made quick friends.

Logically, "went up" should work here (comparing to "go up"), but perhaps the phrasal verb "go up" doesn't have the meaning in my question. So what verb would you use in my self-made example above?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use *to come up*, there's nothing inherently one-sided to this phrasal verb that the first person can only be the object or something.

> When everybody was dancing, I came up to her and after greetings started talking to her and fortunately we made quick friends.

<sub>(note that I have changed 'were' to 'was'; 'everybody' is singular even though it is about multiple persons)</sub>

Comment: Perfect. Actually, I knew that while I saw some similar cases, but I needed to inquire whether there is a better and more direct verb for that or not. Thank you very much @Glorfindel. Meanwhile, sorry for the badic mistake. I editted my thread. :)